# How to add different CSS files to different layouts in blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

Hi every blazor lover!

I have 2 different layouts and, I want to load different CSS file on each layout.

The first one is MainLayout.razor and the other is AdminLayout.razor.

I want to load my admin menu CSS file in the AdminLayout, without using "css isolation", because the CSS files for this layout maybe more files in future.

ASP.NET Core 3.1 or .NET 5.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution for .Net 3.1 or .Net 5.0**

use this java script to add css file to page or layout directly:

```js
    function loadCss(cssPath) {
        var ss = document.styleSheets;
        for (var i = 0, max = ss.length; i < max; i++) {
            if (ss[i].href.includes(cssPath.substr(2)))
                return;
        }
        var link = document.createElement("link");
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.href = cssPath;
    
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
    }
```

I create a js function "loadCss", you have to call this function on OnAfterRenderAsync event:

```cs
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("loadCss", "css/FILENAME.min.css");
    }
```

Comment: You are using JS though, and we want to be avoiding that if we can

Comment: you can use <link ...> inside the html body everywhere. check other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTML `<link>` tag anywhere in the `<head>` or `<body>` to include CSS, so drop the appropriate `<link rel="stylesheet" href="..." />` into MainLayout.razor and AdminLayout.razor, respectively.

Eventually, adding content to the `<head>` directly from a razor component may be supported, as [tracked here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25705).

Comment: thanks, its worked. but in this case, the <link> placed inside of body. I think maybe there is a better way to add <link> to head instead of inside <body>.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it can also be done this way. Using `HeadOutlet` and `HeadContent`.
The reference article is here: [Control  content in ASP.NET Core Blazor apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/control-head-content?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: yes, we can use <headOutlet> tag on .NET 6.0+